# What is the best way of using database host?

Tags: php, database, mariadb, webserver

How to choose a web server?

I have a website and it has good traffic.
But the problem is that the database gets over thousands hit per seconds so I would like to get suggestions from you guys.

The server is capable of handling much traffic but MariaDB service gets off so What should I do?

I was thinking to use remote databases and a CDN server for contents.
Current server + Database server + CDN Server.

Does anyone have a better suggestion that will help me to get rid of the problem and also reduce the cost of  CDN/database servers??

[Sorry for my grammatical mistakes]

Comment: Questions on **professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

Comment: Start by figuring out if you've got slow running queries, [n+1 issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping), etc. The issue may be the code rather than the database itself - if you're getting thousands of database hits but *not* thousands of *pageviews* a second, you probably need to work on paring that down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but MariaDB service gets off so

I have no idea what this means.

> I was thinking to use remote databases and a CDN server for contents

If you are serving content directly from your database then you will have performance problems. However using a CDN is only going to help if:

1. A large part of your customer base has a long RTT to your server
2. You have already optimized the caching of your content

If 1 is not the case, then you'll get as much benefit running your own cache. If 2 is the case then you're either going to have to fix your caching or enhance your database capacity.

> gets over thousands hit per seconds

So what? Depending on the queries and the hardware, that might be a a constraint on your service performance. It might not. Tuning your DBMS and queries might help.

Answer (score 2):

- Readonly Slaves can be used to provide 'infinite' *read* scaling.
- Turn on the slowlog, etc, to find the 'worst' queries to improve on.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog
- Galera Clustering *may* provide a small amount of *write* scaling.
- Combining queries *may* help some.